# Right align horizontal menu css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a Netflix Clone website and my right menu won't align horizontally. I'm getting an error that the css property is being ignored because of "display:inline-block" but I'm not getting the same error for my left menu. Any suggestions would be more than welcome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title> 
            Couch Cinematics
        </title>
            <style>
            #header{
                background: rgb(233, 225, 178);
                color: white;
                overflow: auto;
                padding-left: 25px;
                padding-right: 25px;
            }
                .logo{
                    text-align: left;
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: lightpink;
                    margin-right: 25px;
                    padding: 20px;
                }
                .leftMenu{
                    text-align: left;
                    display: inline-block;
                    background:lightpink;
                }
                .leftMenu ul{
                    list-style: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .leftMenu ul li{
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding: 20px;

                }
                .rightMenu{
                    float: right;
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: lightpink;
                }
                .rightMenu ul{
                    list-style: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .rightMenu ul li{
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding: 20px;
                }

            </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to align text to right like the left menu is aligned to left. Try it with and without the right float to find which one will work.

```
.rightMenu{
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightpink;
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but it doesn't make my menu list horizontal or put it far enough to the right

Comment: try change the display to `inline`

Comment: I've tried that as well but the list won't display horizonally